# How can I share data (props or other way) between sibling components using React router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I am trying to create a Router link on my to-do list, I have placed the route tags on the app component where the two components I want to toggle are placed, nevertheless I want to share some data (an array of objects between the components and I don't know how this can be implemented, my todo list is made of 3 components, I will place the first one where the functions are and the other ones are the inputs and the todo divs where I show the specific todo. How can I implement a button on a particular todo div that takes me to the Detail tag on the router component to render a dynamic component for each todo and also share the complete list of todos to the todo detail?

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Route exact strict path ='/'>
          <TodoList />
        </Route>
        <Route exact strict path ='/:todo'>
          <TodoDetail />
        </Route>
      </Router>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;



-----------------------------------------------------------

function TodoList () {

const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

const addTodo = (todo) => {

    const newTodos = [...todos, todo];

    setTodos(newTodos);

    
    

}

const handleDelete = (id) => {

    const deletedTodos = [...todos].filter(todo => todo.id !== id); 

    setTodos(deletedTodos);
}

const toggleComplete = (id) => {

    const updatedTodos = [...todos].map(todo => {
        if(todo.id === id) {
            todo.completed = !todo.completed
        }
        return todo
    })

    setTodos(updatedTodos);
}


const updatedTodos = (id, newValue) => {

    setTodos(prevState => prevState.map(todo => todo.id === id ? newValue: todo))

}




    return (
        <div className= 'tasklist'>
            <h1>Your to do list!</h1>
            <TodoForm  onSubmit={addTodo}/>
            <div className= 'all-todos'>
            <TodoDivs list={todos} Delete={handleDelete} 
            Completed={toggleComplete} Update={updatedTodos}/>
            </div>
            
            
        </div>

    )
}

export default TodoList;
```

Comment: You can take advantage of the Context API to achieve what you want. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext -> For more details.

Comment: Hi! thanks I actually thought about this, but my array is coming from within to-do, so I haven't figured out how to pull it all the way up to use it as context

Comment: context or redux , context is easier … if you need general store use redux . docs are your best friend

Comment: @Walter inside your context declares useState and in todos use set and state at component u want to share it

Comment: Just to update I could solve this issue in an easier way using the React router hook useLocation, nice tool to share a path and some props